# MDT 2012 Autologin fails

Tags: mdt-2012

When running a task on MDT 2012, it fails to auto login and finish it's processes. I verified that the registry is not updated to autologin. I also verified that the info was correct the unattend.xml. Any reason as to what would cause this. Why wouldn't it modify the registry to auto login?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After the WINPE portion? MDT does not create the auto login registry information, Sysprep does (at this stage). Most likely this is a Sysprep issue rather than an MDT issue. Take MDT out of the equation and try to Sysprep with the exact same parameters. You can also use the Sysprep logs to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to login as the local administrator? If so, did you activate the account? By default, the local administrator account is disabled and needs to be enabled. The TechNet article ‘[Enable and Disable the Built-in Administrator Account](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744293(v=ws.10).aspx)’ shows you how.

Are you using the SLSHARE setting in your deployment share rules to collect the log files from the deployment? The help files in MDT show you how to set this. Basically, create a folder in your deployment share named ‘Logs’ and then in your deployment share rules, add the SLSHARE setting:

SLSHARE=\Server\Deploymentshare$\Logs

Once this is done, all the log files will be uploaded to your deployment share for each deployment to help you with troubleshooting issues with your deployments.

Hope this helps,